# Issues with generating ggiNEXT graph

Tags: r, inext

After resolving [my previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61446700/error-message-incorrect-number-of-subscripts-when-trying-to-use-inext), I've come to the next problem.

This time I believe it involves interpreting the results and is an issue with the data collected.

Here's the steps I took:

```
#load packages

library(iNEXT)

#data here
ct <-structure(list(Station = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("CT01", 
"CT02", "CT03"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(10L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 2L), .Label = c("1/11/19", "13/11/19", "14/11/19", 
"15/11/19", "17/11/19", "18/11/19", "22/11/19", "23/11/19", "25/10/19", 
"26/10/19", "27/10/10", "27/10/19", "28/10/19", "29/10/19", "3/11/19", 
"30/10/19", "31/10/19", "6/11/19", "7/11/19"), class = "factor"), 
    Time = structure(c(23L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 24L, 15L, 31L, 20L, 
    18L, 19L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 16L, 17L, 21L, 9L, 14L), .Label = c("0:34:24", 
    "0:43:46", "13:07:10", "16:49:34", "17:26:28", "19:06:56", 
    "19:11:56", "19:13:28", "19:34:58", "19:53:00", "19:56:42", 
    "2:33:36", "2:34:40", "20:21:42", "20:27:00", "20:31:42", 
    "20:32:08", "22:25:22", "23:19:00", "23:50:24", "23:50:44", 
    "3:19:00", "4:26:00", "4:28:00", "4:46:00", "4:56:04", "5:13:32", 
    "5:18:00", "5:19:00", "5:56:00", "6:31:00"), class = "factor"), 
    DateTimeOriginal = structure(c(18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
    20L, 17L, 22L, 23L, 1L, 2L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 24L, 
    25L, 3L), .Label = c("1/11/19 0:43", "1/11/19 19:13", "13/11/19 20:21", 
    "14/11/19 17:26", "15/11/19 19:56", "17/11/19 0:34", "18/11/19 4:56", 
    "22/11/19 5:13", "23/11/19 2:33", "23/11/19 2:34", "3/11/19 13:07", 
    "3/11/19 19:06", "3/11/19 19:11", "3/11/19 20:31", "3/11/19 20:32", 
    "30/10/19 23:22", "30/10/19 23:50", "30/10/19 23:58", "30/10/19 23:59", 
    "31/10/19 0:00", "31/10/19 16:49", "31/10/19 22:25", "31/10/19 23:19", 
    "6/11/19 23:50", "7/11/19 19:34"), class = "factor"), Scientific_name_1 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Callosciurus_notatus", "Rattus_tiomanicus"
    ), class = "factor"), Abundance_1 = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L
    )), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")


ct$trapnights <- paste(ct$Station, ct$Date, sep="_") 

#create contingency table
ct.matrix <- xtabs(Abundance_1~Scientific_name_1+trapnights, data=ct)


#create species incidence matrix
ct.df1 <- ifelse(ct.matrix>0,1,0) 

#convert matrix > list
ct.df2<- list(ct.df1)

#run iNEXT
(ct.inext <- iNEXT(ct.df2, datatype="incidence_raw"))

# plot graph 
ggiNEXT(ct.inext, type=3)
```

At this point, I get this error

```
Error in data.frame(do.call("rbind", z), site = rep(names(z), sapply(z,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 40, 0
```

I wonder if it has to do with my actual data (maybe the fact that I have only one assemblage? I checked ct.inext and it gave me a sample coverage of 1 (see below: 100% sample coverage--is that even possible?)

```
> ct.inext

Compare 1 assemblages with Hill number order q = .
$class: iNEXT

$DataInfo: basic data information
    site  T  U S.obs SC Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 Q8 Q9 Q10
1 site.1 14 15     2  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0

$iNextEst: diversity estimates with rarefied and extrapolated samples.
[[1]]
    t       method order    qD qD.LCL qD.UCL    SC SC.LCL SC.UCL
1   1 interpolated     0 1.071  0.922  1.221 0.933  0.828  1.000
2   1 interpolated     0 1.071  0.922  1.221 0.933  0.828  1.000
10  7 interpolated     0 1.500  0.839  2.161 0.933  0.878  0.989
11  7 interpolated     0 1.500  0.839  2.161 0.933  0.878  0.989
20 14     observed     0 2.000  1.111  2.889 1.000  1.000  1.000
30 21 extrapolated     0 2.000  1.111  2.889 1.000  1.000  1.000
31 21 extrapolated     0 2.000  1.111  2.889 1.000  1.000  1.000
40 28 extrapolated     0 2.000  1.111  2.889 1.000  1.000  1.000
```

Again, any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a tweak. The error is because that ct.inext$iNextEst in unnamed. I just assigned a random name for ct.inext$iNextEst and it gave the plot.

```
ct$trapnights <- paste(ct$Station, ct$Date, sep="_") 
ct.matrix <- xtabs(Abundance_1~Scientific_name_1+trapnights, data=ct)
ct.df1 <- ifelse(ct.matrix>0,1,0) 
ct.df2<- list(ct.df1)
(ct.inext <- iNEXT(ct.df2, datatype="incidence_raw"))

names(ct.inext$iNextEst) <- "Abundance"

ggiNEXT(ct.inext, type=3, facet.var="none")
```

[image]

```
ggiNEXT(ct.inext, type=2, facet.var="none")
```

[image]

I a m not sure whether this is the answer you are expecting. I just pointed out the reason why the plot is not generating for your code.

**P.S.:** 
Since, I am not familiar with this analysis, I couldn't get why you are converting the Abundance values into binary, while the examples that I had looked at were not in binary.

Comment: Thank you for the help! One qn: how did you know that it was the issue with the unnaming? 

Also, naming wasn't needed based on the example in the documentation: data(ciliates). Do you know why the difference?

Comment: To answer your qn, there was an error in creating the list, where both Callosciurus_notatus and Rattus_tiomanicus added to a single component of the list. Now, I have updated my answer with the correct way of creating the list based on Callosciurus_notatus and Rattus_tiomanicus. I believe that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: How I found out  the missing name?  In do.call("rbind", z), z nothing but ct.inext$iNextEst and I tried running this do.call with ct.inext$iNextEst instead of z which helped me to locate the problem. Anyway, it was due to wrong way of creating the list.

Comment: RE the second part of your question. The binary is because we're generating a species incidence matrix (presence/absence of species per sampling point). There are a few different examples with diff data types in the iNEXT documentation--ciliates is the one I'm following. The better name for $iNextEst would thus be Mammals (Camera Trapping). Thank you for asking!

Comment: Your initial answer was correct actually! I'm trying to estimate the number of mammal species in a forest (seen & unseen). Only C_notatus and R_tiomanicus were recorded and the iNEXT is supposed to estimate the extent of sample completeness (how thorough my surveys were) and then how many total species there likely is based on the rate of new species encountered. So in a species-poor forest (where we aren't encountering new species regularly), usually estimates would be close to whatever has been observed and sample coverage / completeness would be close to one. Which is likely the case here.